# PowerShell -- Accessing a JArray inside a JObject

Tags: json, powershell, json.net

I have a Json object

```
 {
  "ProjectDirectory": "C:\\Main",
  "SiteName": "RemoteOrder",
  "ParentPath": "/Areas//Views",
  "VirtualDirectories": [
        {
          "Name": "Alerts",
          "Path": "\\Areas\\RemoteOrder\\Views\\Alerts"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Analytics",
          "Path": "\\Areas\\RemoteOrder\\Views\\Analytics"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Auth",
          "Path": "\\Areas\\RemoteOrder\\Views\\Auth"
        }
    ]
}
```

that I created by

```
$config = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($file)
```

I can access things like

```
$config["ProjectDirectory"]
$config["VirtualDirectories"]
```

But I can not get to the element inside the VirtualDirectories JArray

I confirmed

```
 $config["VirtualDirectories"][0].GetType() // JObject
 $config["VirtualDirectories"].GetType() // JArray
 $config // JObject
```

I have tried

```
$config["VirtualDirectories"][0]["Name"]
$config["VirtualDirectories"][0]["Path"]
$config["VirtualDirectories"][0][0]
$config["VirtualDirectories"][0].GetValue("Name")
```

When I try

```
 $config["VirtualDirectories"][0].ToString()
```

I get

```
{
      "Name": "Alerts",
      "Path": "\\Areas\\RemoteOrder\\Views\\Alerts"
}
```

What I am really trying to do is access it a loop but again I can not seem to access the JObject Elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  `$config["VirtualDirectories"][0]["Name"]` will give you a `JValue` containing the text.  You just need to use the `Value` property from there to get the actual string.  Here is how you would do it in a `ForEach` loop:

```
$config = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($file)

ForEach ($dir in $config["VirtualDirectories"])
{
    $name = $dir["Name"].Value
    $path = $dir["Path"].Value
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To *complement* [Brian Rogers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44656215/45375):

As a more convenient alternative to *index* syntax (`["<name>"]`) you can use *property* syntax
(`.<name>`), because the `JObject` instances returned have *dynamic properties* named for their keys:

```
$config = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($file)

foreach ($dir in $config.VirtualDirectories) {
  $name = $dir.Name.Value # as in Brian's answer: note the need for .Value
  $path = $dir.Path.Value # ditto
  # Sample output
  "$name=$path" # outputs 'Alerts=\Areas\RemoteOrder\Views\Alerts', ...
}
```

I presume that the reason you chose to **work with [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) types *directly*** is **performance** compared to PowerShell's built-in `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet.

- As an aside: There is a [*PowerShell wrapper* for Json.NET](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/newtonsoft.json/1.0.1.90) that you can install with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser newtonsoft.json` , for instance, which implicitly gives you access to the `[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]` type. However, this wrapper - which represents objects as *ordered hashtables* - is **even slower than `ConvertFrom-Json`**.
- Aside from performance, the following **limitations of `ConvertFrom-Json`** may make it necessary to use a third-party library such as Json.Net anyway:

  - Empty-string keys are not supported.
  - Keys that differ in *case* only (e.g., `foo` vs. `Foo`) are not supported.

---

For contrast, here's the **equivalent - but generally slower - `ConvertFrom-Json` solution**:

`ConvertFrom-Json` represents the JSON objects as `[pscustomobject]` instances whose properties are named for the keys, allowing for a more natural syntax without the need to access `.Value`:

```
$config = ConvertFrom-Json $json

foreach ($dir in $config.VirtualDirectories) {
  $name = $dir.Name  # no .Value needed 
  $path = $dir.Path  # ditto
  # Sample output
  "$name=$path" # outputs 'Alerts=\Areas\RemoteOrder\Views\Alerts', ...
}
```