# Cannot retrieve ARM output array in powershell when using New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment

Tags: arrays, json, azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have a simple ARM template that outputs an array of elements. I am trying to retrieve said array of elements in powershell, but nothing seems to help. It seems like the deployment result does contain the values of the array, but as soon as I try to navigate to it they become empty strings.

Ideally I want to retrieve the array output from the ARM template into a powershell variable.

ARM template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
    "test": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[variables('test')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Everything I have tried:

Powershell code:

```
$name = ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmmss')
$deploymentResult = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
    -Name $name `
    -ResourceGroupName test4 `
    -TemplateFile 'test2.json' `
    -Force -Verbose `
    -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages

if ($ErrorMessages) {
    Write-Output '', 'Template deployment returned the following errors:', @(@($ErrorMessages) | ForEach-Object { $_.Exception.Message.TrimEnd("`r`n") })
}

Write-Output $deploymentResult
Write-Host ($deploymentResult.outputs | Format-Table | Out-String)

Write-Host "Outputs:" $deploymentResult.outputs
Write-Host "Outputs.value:" $deploymentResult.outputs.value
Write-Host "Outputs.values:" $deploymentResult.outputs.values
Write-Host "Outputs[0]:" $deploymentResult.outputs[0]
Write-Host "Outputs[1]:" $deploymentResult.outputs[1]
Write-Host "Outputs[0].value:" $deploymentResult.outputs[0].value
Write-Host "Outputs[1].value:" $deploymentResult.outputs[1].value
Write-Host "Outputs.result:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result
Write-Host "Outputs.result.value:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result.value
Write-Host "Outputs.result.values:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result.values
Write-Host "Outputs.result[0]:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[0]
Write-Host "Outputs.result[1]:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[1]
Write-Host "Outputs.result[0].value:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[0].value
Write-Host "Outputs.result[1].value:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[1].value
Write-Host "Outputs.result[0][0]:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[0][0]
Write-Host "Outputs.result.value1:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result.value1
Write-Host "Outputs.result[0].value1:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[0].value1

Write-Host
Write-Host "Outputs.values:" $deploymentResult.outputs.values
Write-Host "Outputs.result.Count:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result.Count
Write-Host "Outputs.result:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result
Write-Host "Outputs.result[0]:" $deploymentResult.outputs.result[0]
Write-Host "Outputs['result']:" $deploymentResult.outputs['result']

Write-Host
Write-Host "Deployment properties:"
($deploymentResult) | Select-Object -Property *
Write-Host "Outputs properties:"
($deploymentResult.outputs) | Select-Object -Property *
Write-Host "Result properties:"
($deploymentResult.outputs.result) | Select-Object -Property *
Write-Host "['Result'] properties:"
$deploymentResult.outputs['result'] | Select-Object -Property *
Write-Host "[array]['Result'] properties:"
[array]$deploymentResult.outputs['result'] | Select-Object -Property *
Write-Host "Outputs.values properties:"
($deploymentResult.outputs.values) | Select-Object -Property *

Write-Host
ForEach ($res in $deploymentResult.outputs['result']){
    Write-Host "Result element:" $res
}

Write-Host
ForEach ($res in $deploymentResult.outputs.values){
    Write-Host "Values element:" $res
}

Write-Host
Write-Host "JSON:"
Write-Host "Deployment ConvertTo-Json:"
$json = ($deploymentResult) | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $json
Write-Host "Outputs ConvertTo-Json:"
$json = ($deploymentResult.outputs) | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $json
Write-Host "Result.Value ConvertTo-Json:"
$json = ($deploymentResult.outputs.result.value) | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $json
```

Powershell output:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "test4".
VERBOSE: 11:00:26 - Template is valid.
VERBOSE: 11:00:26 - Create template deployment '0521-100025'
VERBOSE: 11:00:26 - Checking deployment status in 5 seconds


DeploymentName          : 0521-100025
ResourceGroupName       : test4
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 21/05/2020 10:00:26
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
Parameters              :
Outputs                 :
                          Name             Type                       Value
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          result           Array                      [
                            "value1",
                            "value2"
                          ]

DeploymentDebugLogLevel :


Key    Value
---    -----
result Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable



Outputs: [result, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable]
Outputs.value:
Outputs.values: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs[0]:
Outputs[1]:
Outputs[0].value:
Outputs[1].value:
Outputs.result: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs.result.value:
Outputs.result.values:
Outputs.result[0]: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs.result[1]:
Outputs.result[0].value:
Outputs.result[1].value:
Outputs.result[0][0]: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs.result.value1:
Outputs.result[0].value1:

Outputs.values: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs.result.Count: 1
Outputs.result: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs.result[0]: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable
Outputs['result']: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable

Deployment properties:

ResourceGroupName       : test4
OnErrorDeployment       :
DeploymentName          : 0521-100025
CorrelationId           : 10be00bb-fada-4b54-8749-87460672e9ec
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 21/05/2020 10:00:26
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
TemplateLinkString      :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
Parameters              : {}
ParametersString        :
Outputs                 : {[result, Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable]}
OutputsString           :
                          Name             Type                       Value
                          ===============  =========================  ==========
                          result           Array                      [
                            "value1",
                            "value2"
                          ]


Outputs properties:

Comparer       : System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]
Count          : 1
Keys           : {result}
Values         : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : False
SyncRoot       : System.Object
IsSynchronized : False

Result properties:

Type  : Array
Value : {, }

['Result'] properties:

Type  : Array
Value : {, }

[array]['Result'] properties:

Type  : Array
Value : {, }

Outputs.values properties:

Type  : Array
Value : {, }


Result element: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable

Values element: Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.DeploymentVariable

JSON:
Deployment ConvertTo-Json:
{
    "ResourceGroupName":  "test4",
    "OnErrorDeployment":  null,
    "DeploymentName":  "0521-100025",
    "CorrelationId":  "10be00bb-fada-4b54-8749-87460672e9ec",
    "ProvisioningState":  "Succeeded",
    "Timestamp":  "\/Date(1590055226689)\/",
    "Mode":  0,
    "TemplateLink":  null,
    "TemplateLinkString":  null,
    "DeploymentDebugLogLevel":  null,
    "Parameters":  {

                   },
    "ParametersString":  "",
    "Outputs":  {
                    "result":  {
                                   "Type":  "Array",
                                   "Value":  "value1 value2"
                               }
                },
    "OutputsString":  "\r\nName             Type                       Value     \r\n===============  =========================  ==========\r\nresult           Array                      [\r\n  \"value1\",\r\n  \"value2\"\r\n]\r\n"
}
Outputs ConvertTo-Json:
{
    "result":  {
                   "Type":  "Array",
                   "Value":  [
                                 "",
                                 ""
                             ]
               }
}
Result.Value ConvertTo-Json:
[
    [

    ],
    [

    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array output is in fact a JArray. Access the result like this: `$deploymentResult.outputs.result.value[0].value` and `$deploymentResult.outputs.result.value[1].value`.

More info: [PowerShell -- Accessing a JArray inside a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653771/powershell-accessing-a-jarray-inside-a-jobject)